# How to set multiple UITableview in single ViewController

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

I'm trying to make two TableViews in one ViewController and 
having a trouble in `cellForRowAt indexPath`

I tried `var cell:UITableviewCell?` , `return cell!`
 and now `let cell = UITableViewCell()` but it's still not working

```
@IBOutlet weak var ButtonA: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var ATV: UITableView!

@IBOutlet weak var ButtonB: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var BTV: UITableView! 


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = UITableViewCell()

    if tableView == self.ATV {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = Alist[indexPath.row]
        let bgColorView = UIView()
        bgColorView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.93, green:0.60, blue:0.49, alpha:0.5)
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = bgColorView
    }

    if tableView == self.BTV {
        let cell1 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell1", for: indexPath)
        cell1.textLabel?.text = Blist[indexPath.row]}

        return cell            
    }
```

I want each button to have a different list

Comment: You can separate this tables on different UIViewControllers where each UITableView has own UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate. Then add they as child controllers to parent container with frame which needed

Comment: You are not returning cell when "tableView == self.ATV"

Comment: The best way is to have one ViewController with several TableView and create several TableViewHandlers that will implement protocol methods to fill up your table views. Then just set to your tableviews data sources different instances of your handlers